# How to deserialize this JSON with JsonConvert.DeserializeObject

Tags: c#, json, serialization, deserialization

I am trying to deserialize this JSON, but I keep getting errors. Can someone please help me? Where did I make a mistake?

```
JSON:

{
    "totalItems": 63,
    "items": [
    {
        "id": 100039812,
        "group": {
            "code": "DD",
            "description": "Delivery Documents"
        },
        "type": {
            "code": "READ",
            "description": "Logs"
        },
        "reference": "ARLDR",
        "date": "2015-03-24T00:00:00",
        "description": "ALogs",
        "notes": "",
        "lastUpdateDate": "2015-03-24T14:06:42.063",
        "location": "BOX A001",
        "metadata": {}
    },
    {
        "id": 100039813,
        "group": {
            "code": "DD",
            "description": "Delivery Documents"
        },
        "type": {
            "code": "BL",
            "description": "Logbooks"
        },
        "reference": "BALB",
        "date": "2015-03-24T00:00:00",
        "description": "Logbooks",
        "notes": "",
        "lastUpdateDate": "2015-03-24T14:07:42.44",
        "location": "BOX A001",
        "metadata": {}
        }
    ]
}

public class Documents
{
    public int totalItems  { get; set; }
    public List<doc_items> items { get; set; }
}

public class doc_items
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public List<group_items> group { get; set; }
    public List<type_items> type { get; set; }
    public string reference { get; set; }
    public string date { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public string notes { get; set; }
    public string lastUpdateDate { get; set; }
    public string location { get; set; }
    public List<metadata_list> metadata { get; set; }
}

public class group_items
{
    public string code { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
}

public class type_items
{
    public string code { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
}

public class metadata_list
{

}
```

Then I call this:

```
Documents myDocuments = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Documents>(responsetext.ToString());
```

and receive the following error:

> Error:  Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException:
>     Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type  System.Collections.Generic.List`1[AerData.Ranorex.Web.Records.API_Documents+Documents]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [...

Comment: Paste your json string into a new class file using EDIT -> Paste Special -> Paste JSON as classes, or use http://jsonutils.com/ - your classes dont quite match

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the contrary 'group', 'type' and 'metadata' are not arrays so modify your class to:

```
public class doc_items
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public group_items group { get; set; }
    public type_items type { get; set; }
    public string reference { get; set; }
    public string date { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public string notes { get; set; }
    public string lastUpdateDate { get; set; }
    public string location { get; set; }
    public metadata_list metadata { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Given from the definition of the `Documents` class, the `group` property of an `doc_items` has to be an array. In your given JSON it's an object. The same holds for the `type` property

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using a converter like this: http://json2csharp.com/#

Try this:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var sr = new StreamReader("json.json");
        var jsonText = sr.ReadToEnd();
        Documents myDocuments = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Documents>(jsonText);
    }
}

public class group_items
{
    public string code { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
}

public class type_items
{
    public string code { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
}

public class metadata_list
{
}

public class doc_items
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public group_items GroupItems { get; set; }
    public type_items TypeItems { get; set; }
    public string reference { get; set; }
    public string date { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public string notes { get; set; }
    public string lastUpdateDate { get; set; }
    public string location { get; set; }
    public metadata_list MetadataList { get; set; }
}

public class Documents
{
    public int totalItems { get; set; }
    public List<doc_items> items { get; set; }
}
```

Your data file `json.json`

```
{
  "totalItems": 63,
  "items": [
    {
      "id": 100039812,
      "group": {
        "code": "DD",
        "description": "Delivery Documents"
      },
      "type": {
        "code": "READ",
        "description": "Logs"
      },
      "reference": "ARLDR",
      "date": "2015-03-24T00:00:00",
      "description": "ALogs",
  "notes": "",
  "lastUpdateDate": "2015-03-24T14:06:42.063",
  "location": "BOX A001",
  "metadata": { }
},
{
  "id": 100039813,
  "group": {
    "code": "DD",
    "description": "Delivery Documents"
  },
  "type": {
    "code": "BL",
    "description": "Logbooks"
  },
  "reference": "BALB",
  "date": "2015-03-24T00:00:00",
  "description": "Logbooks",
  "notes": "",
  "lastUpdateDate": "2015-03-24T14:07:42.44",
  "location": "BOX A001",
  "metadata": { }
    }
  ]
}
```